# Accessing href link using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the href of the first link titled "BACC B ET A COMPTABILITE CONSEIL". However, I can't seem to extract the href when I'm using BeautifulSoup. Could you please recommend a solution?

Here's the link to the url - https://www.pappers.fr/recherche?q=B+%26+A+COMPTABILITE+CONSEIL&ville=94160

My code:

```
              url = 'https://www.pappers.fr/recherche?q=B+%26+A+COMPTABILITE+CONSEIL&ville=94160'
              headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, 
              like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36'}
              resp = requests.get(str(url), headers=headers)
              soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, 'html.parser')

              a = soup.find('div', {'class': 'nom-entreprise'})
              print(a)
```

Result:

None.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link is constructed dynamically with JavaScript. All you need is a number, which is obtained with Ajax query:

```py
import json
import requests

# url = "https://www.pappers.fr/recherche?q=B+%26+A+COMPTABILITE+CONSEIL&ville=94160"
api_url = "https://api.pappers.fr/v2/recherche"

payload = {
    "q": "B & A COMPTABILITE CONSEIL",  # <-- your search query
    "code_naf": "",
    "code_postal": "94160",  # <-- this is "ville" from URL
    "api_token": "97a405f1664a83329a7d89ebf51dc227b90633c4ba4a2575",
    "precision": "standard",
    "bases": "entreprises,dirigeants,beneficiaires,documents,publications",
    "page": "1",
    "par_page": "20",
}

data = requests.get(api_url, params=payload).json()

# uncomment this to print all data (all details):
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

print("https://www.pappers.fr/entreprise/" + data["resultats"][0]["siren"])
```

Prints:

```
https://www.pappers.fr/entreprise/378002208
```

Opening the link will automatically redirects to:

```
https://www.pappers.fr/entreprise/bacc-b-et-a-comptabilite-conseil-378002208
```

Answer (score 1):

The website uses is loaded dynamically, therefore `requests` doesn't support it. We can use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) as an alternative to scrape the page.

Install it with: `pip install selenium`.

Download the correct ChromeDriver from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads).

---

To find the links you can use a CSS selector: `a.gros-gros-nom`

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://www.pappers.fr/recherche?q=B+%26+A+COMPTABILITE+CONSEIL&ville=94160"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

# Wait for the link to be visible on the page and save element to a variable `link`
link = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.gros-gros-nom"))
)

print(link.get_attribute("href"))


driver.quit()
```

Output:

```
https://www.pappers.fr/entreprise/bacc-b-et-a-comptabilite-conseil-378002208
```